# Sharepoint 2013 Claims Based Authentication And Azure ACS - Windows Live Id Redirects back to Sign In

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I am having a issue with Claims Based Authentication through Windows Azure ACS.  I have set up my trusted relationships and can see them inside of my Sharepoint 2013 website.  I have set up both Google and Windows Live to be used.  When I log in with my Google account everything works as expected and I am directed to the sites home page.  However every time I try my Windows Live account it just redirects back to the Sign In Page every time with no errors.

Ken

Comment: Did you set up nameidentifier to UPN claim?  Windows Live doesn't provide an emailaddress claim.  I am seeing the same issue, and I think that's what it is.  Which guide did you use?

Comment: Try this - go to central admin and on the web app, add everyone from your trusted provider as a reader.  Then, in the Azure acs rules group, set the rule for windows live id to output an emailaddress claim.  When you login, it might give you the 'sorry, this site hasn't been shared with you' page, but try to hit the site again, and you'll be allowed in...the id of the user will be a cryptic string.  I think it has to do with how live id handles claims when you are not a trusted microsoft partner.

Comment: That is what I kind of expected as well.  I stopped working on that for a bit as I got Google to log in just fine and right now I'm just trying to POC how all three of the authentication capabilities work.

Comment: @kav : Is it possible to translate the cryptic string to a human readable ID, e.g. email address? I'd like to know how I could use the people picker in my Shaerpoint web app to add individual users.